# how to control the outugoing order of multiple emails from .NET sendgrid

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, smtp, sendgrid

If my .NET app sends out one email followed by another, sometimes the 2nd arrives 1st.

Is there a way to control the order they get sent.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, email delivery is a function of the server. The best you can do is to delay the second email by some arbitrary amount of time, but even that is no guarantee. You could maybe  use a scheduling component to facilitate that. Why does the order matter? Maybe knowing that will help us find an answer for you.